# I want to know the speed of the wheel when wheel is rotating

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I am rotating the wheel using tweenlite, below is the piece of code

TweenLite.to(wheel, 12, {rotation:720, immediateRender:true, useFrames:false, onUpdate:onTweenUpdate});

When wheel is spinning i want to know the wheel speed for some stuffs. Can i know the speed of the wheel when it is rotating?

Comment: You already have all the values right there, don't you? The wheel rotates for 720° in 12 seconds, i.e 720°/12s = 60° per second. Or what kind of speed do you mean? Be more clear.

Comment: speed will change depending on tween easing, add an onUpdate method (as part of the parameters passed) and check there the actual speed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **@DodgerThud**'s comment.. 
to avoid manual calculation you could put your numbers in `int` variables like so

```
num_rotation : int = 720;
num_time     : int = 12;
num_speed    : int = 0; //updates later
```

Then your tween code could look like..

```
TweenLite.to(wheel, num_time, {rotation:num_rotation, immediateRender:true, useFrames:false, onUpdate:onTweenUpdate});
```

Then like **@BotMaster**'s comment said, inside your **onTweenUpdate** you could have..

```
num_speed = num_rotation / num_time; //update speed calculation
```